# Understanding Android App RAM Usage

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ram

My app uses a service which I start in the main activity's `onCreate()` method. When I first launch the app on my tablet, and view what's running in *Settings/Apps/Running*, it shows my service running and consuming 11MB of RAM.

Now, if I cycle the activity's life cycle 20 times by rotating the device, and go back into *Settings/Apps/Running*, it shows that I'm now using 29MB of RAM.

At first I thought this must be due to a memory leaks, but after taking heap dumps before and after cycling the activity's life cycle, I don't appear to be leaking any objects. Below is a screenshot from MAT, where the column titled `Objects #0` lists instances of my objects before cycling, and column titled `Objects #1` lists instances of my objects after cycling.

[image: My objects after cycling]

and for all objects

[image]

There don't appear to be any obvious memory leaks, and yet I can't understand why the RAM usage in *Settings/Apps/Running* increases after each orientation/lifecycle. Am I missing something here? Why is my RAM usage apparently increasing, when I don't appear to have any memory leaks?

**Update**

The reason my app was consuming more RAM on each orientation change was the result of creating custom fonts from assets. I had created a custom `TypefacedTextView` (can be seen as an object in the screenshots above) that appears to have been reloading the fonts into memory each time the view was created. Removing the `TypefacedTextViews` has fixed the problem. The problem was made clearly apparent using the adb tool with command `shell dumpsys meminfo my.package.com` which listed my abundant font Asset Allocations.

Comment: "My app uses a service which I start in the main activity's onCreate() method, and stop in the activity's onDestroy() method" -- why do you have the service, then?

Comment: @CommonsWare It's not used like that in the 'proper' app. I've put it in there during the debug process of trying to work out why the RAM appears to increase. Leaving the service running during this debug process produces the same effect. Note: I've also remove all functionality from the service, but still get the same result.

Comment: Note also that I'm using a worker fragment to start and bind to the service when the activity is first created. Thus reducing the need to wait for the asynchronous `ServiceConnection` call each time a configuration change takes place (I think this method was described in one of your excellent blogs) :)

Comment: I'd focus on using better tools, like `procstats`, to determine your memory footprint: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/01/process-stats-understanding-how-your.html See also Dianne Hackborn's epic SO answer on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813

Answer (score 0):

There's a short blog post which, I believe, holds a lot of information nonetheless. You can find it [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/).

In it you find an intereseting explanation of what can/will happen if you manage your Activity's references wrongly:

```
private static Drawable sBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  if (sBackground == null) {
    sBackground = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);
  }
  label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);

  setContentView(label);
}
```

> This code is very fast and also very wrong; it leaks the first
>   activity created upon the first screen orientation change. When a
>   Drawable is attached to a view, the view is set as a callback on the
>   drawable. In the code snippet above, this means the drawable has a
>   reference to the TextView which itself has a reference to the activity
>   (the Context) which in turns has references to pretty much anything
>   (depending on your code.)

Since you're talking about memory leaks on orientation changes, you may very well be making the mistakes the author details in his post.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually already been through this post and many like it. I've been fastidious about not holding on to object references longer than necessary, and I don't think that's the problem given the MAT analysis. The problem appears more subtle about using custom fonts. About to open another question on this matter.